# Jquery select parent parent sibling

Tags: jquery

I want to select parent sibbling.
However my Jquery is not working properly although it does not contain any faults.

On click class BLC4 display Modal (in class boxmo).

HTML :

```
<div id="bodypro">
 <div class="product pro">

  <img class="product-img pro" src="imagessc/fxynxo1413781254438.jpg">

   <div class="product-actions pro">
    <div class="nav titlen pro" style="margin-top: 0%;">RAJFOO Gaming Mouse Button</div>
     <div class="nav pro boxp" style="margin-left: 0px;">
      <ul>
       <li class="blc4 data-toggle= active" data-original-title="Product Page" title="" data-placement="left" tooltip"="">
      </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

        <div class="boxmo">
         <div style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal productmodal">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
             <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><i class="text-danger fa icon-remove"></i></button>
             <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title"><i class="text-muted fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>RAJFOO Custom</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="text-left pull-left col-md-6">                     
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY :

```
$j('.blc4').on('click', function(event) {
    $j(this).parent().parent().siblings('.boxmo').find('.productmodal').modal('show');
)}
```

Not working.
I want to select on class click blc4 parent sibbling with class mobox

Comment: Is `$j` your alias for jQuery? What is the context for this code? `$j(this)` is going to depend on the scope where you execute it. How are we supposed to know what's wrong with your code if we don't know the context?

Comment: _"my Jquery is not working properly although it does not contain any faults."_ - well obviously there _is_ a fault, otherwise it would work.

Comment: Great comment, thanks for the contribution

Comment: Presumably by '*does not contain any faults*' you meant 'there are no JavaScript errors reported in the console'? And, honestly, reading your question I'm struggling to make sense of what you want to achieve; this may be because it's late here in the UK, and I may be tired, but if you could possibly rephrase your question (and pare your posted code down to a [minimal, representative sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) that would be a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are one level off, you need another `parent` call for that to work:

```
$j(this).parent().parent().parent().siblings('.boxmo').find('.productmodal').modal('show');
```

It's easier to find a parent using a selector, then find the right child, and it's less dependant on the exact layout:

```
$j(this).closest('#bodypro').find('.boxmo .productmodal').modal('show');
```

Comment: Thanks, the first one is working ! The second one not. What I dont get is the following, why not use parents instead of 3x parent() ?

Comment: You found the correct div from massive html.+1

Comment: @user3710844: I counted wrong on the levels, now the second should work. That level has an id though, so it seems pointless to look for it from the clicked element when it would be unique in the page. I don't know why the first one works, there should actually be even one more `parent` call to get to the right level. Perhaps the code that you posted is not correct? There are three levels of closing tags missing at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing like this:

```
$j(this).parents('#bodypro').find('.productmodal.modal').modal('show');
```

Comment: Not working unfortunately. I was also thinking this way before.